# i cannot run any gradle projects

Tags: gradle

this is the minecraft forges default gradle

i also search but didnt find any answers

```
C:\Users\masiha.DESKTOP-VBVOMDJ\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.3-bin\31t79e2qsceia4mkbojplrgx
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

pleas help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem accrued to me yesterday as well, so I thought I might share my fix to this problem if this is still relevant.

While I am not familiar with Forge at all (I started using Fabric just a few days ago), how I fixed my problem was to change the settings in either the `gradle.properties` or `build.gradle` according to your mod's correct settings.

Most likely your problem occurs in **gradle.properties**. It might be the version number that isn't correct, and a quick research of the current Forge or Minecraft version you're planning on using would help. The same applies to **build.gradle**.

In the crash log you've provided, most of the errors are coming from the class `org.gradle.wrapper.*`, so it's likely to assume that it is something in one of the 2 files.

If neither of that worked, it might be because you've entered an incorrect path to your `main` class in the `forge.mod.json` file.
For example, if your classpath is `hi.mashia.main`, then you'll have to enter it in the 'main' field there as well. This could've happen if you've changed your classpath or name lately, or just installed a new Forge environment and didn't set this thing up.

Again, I'm not using Forge, and I'm just telling my own experience with things.
So if this doesn't help, just try to look for common Gradle errors in the [Gradle User Manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html), or if this doesn't help, then you might want to look into the [Forge Docs](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/l) or something similar to that. Google search or YouTube might help with that too.
A video that I think you could potentially find helpful is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOTH1eDP99Y&t=924s) by TechnoVision.
It might be outdated, but not too outdated.

Really hope this helps!
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm coding Flutter and I had this issue.

Here's how I fixed it:

- Backed-up the `AndroidManifest.xml` file at `/android/app/src/main`
- Deleted the `android` folder
- Ran `flutter create .`
- This generated a fresh `android` folder for me
- Replaced the `AndroidManifest.xml` back with what I had initially
- This fixed it for me